# Parsing issue with my user authentication

Tags: android, firebase, parsing, firebase-authentication

Im trying to create user Authentication for my app. When I try to run my program, it displayes error:reached end of file while parcing
   I tried to check every single line of codes.However, I wasnt able to find where the issue is.Please anybody check my code and help me to find that parsing error 
.......................................................................................................

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RelativeLayout rootLayout;
Button btnSignIn,btnRegister;
FirebaseAuth auth;
FirebaseDatabase db;
DatabaseReference users;
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase){
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));

    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Before setContentView
        CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                                  .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Arhip_font.ttf")
                                   .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                                    .build());


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Init database
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        users = db.getReference("users");

        //Init View
        btnRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        btnSignIn =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);
        rootLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);

        //Event
        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showRegisterDialog();
            }


        });
        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showLoginDialog();
            }
        });
    }

    private void showLoginDialog() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Sign IN");
        dialog.setMessage("Please use email to Sign IN");
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View login_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_login,null);

        final MaterialEditText edtEmail = login_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);
        final MaterialEditText edtPassword = login_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);

        dialog.setView(login_layout);
        //Set buttom
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Sign In", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
                //Check validation
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtEmail.getText().toString())) {
                    Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Please enter email adress", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtPassword.getText().toString())) {
                    Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Please enter password", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (edtPassword.getText().toString().length() < 6) {
                    Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Password is too short", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
//Login
                auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(edtEmail.getText().toString(), edtPassword.getText().toString()).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Welcome.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Failed " + e.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                });
            }
              });
        dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });


        dialog.show();


        }
    private void showRegisterDialog() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle("REGISTER");
        dialog.setMessage("Please use email to register");
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View register_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_register,null);

        final MaterialEditText edtEmail = register_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);
        final MaterialEditText edtPassword = register_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
        final MaterialEditText edtName = register_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtName);
        final MaterialEditText edtPhone = register_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtPhone);

        dialog.setView(register_layout);
        //Set buttom
        dialog.setPositiveButton("REGISTER", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
                //Check validation
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtEmail.getText().toString())) {
                    Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Please enter email adress", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtName.getText().toString())) {
                    Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Please enter Name", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtPhone.getText().toString())) {
                    Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Please enter Phone number", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (edtPassword.getText().toString().length() < 6) {
                    Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Password is too short", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                //Register now user
                auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(edtEmail.getText().toString(), edtPassword.getText().toString())
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                                //Save user to db
                                User user = new User();
                                user.setEmail(edtEmail.getText().toString());
                                user.setName(edtName.getText().toString());
                                user.setEmail(edtEmail.getText().toString());
                                user.setPhone(edtPhone.getText().toString());
                                //User email to key
                                users.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                        .setValue(user)
                                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {


@Override
                                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                                Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Register Success", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Failed " + e.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Failed " + e.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
                dialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();

            }
            }
```

Comment: The error which is?

Comment: error with closing brackets

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: There is only error message saying:reached end of file while parsing